# matlab (simple edit work needed from the program given)

Tags: matlab

the program below is selective repeat protocol to transmit randomly generated frames and some times enter error in transmitting frames. total number of frames , window size and length of frame is given dynamically by user. if the window size is 3 and no of frames as 7 ,the protocol send 1st three frames generated and sends next three generated bits after receiving the 1st three frames and at last remaining 7th frame is transmitted after receiving previously transmitted frames. then after complete transmission , acknowledgement is received. if there is a error in sending 2nd frame , only after retransmission on 2nd frame , the next set of three frames are sent.  if length of frame is given as 4 , then each frame will have 5 bits( length of frame + one parity bit)

```
%while(b==1)
clc;
m=input('Enter the total no of frames:');
n=input('Enter the window size:');
t=input('Enter the length of frames:');
disp(sprintf('\n'));
while(m~=0)
if(m<n)
n=m;
end
for i=1:1:n;
d=randint(1,t);
d(t+1)=rem(sum(d),2);
a(i,1:t+1)=d;
disp(sprintf('Transmitting frame %d :',i));
disp(a(i,1:t+1));
end
p=randint(1,1,[1,n]);
q=randint(1,1,[1,t+1]);
a(p,q)=randint(1,1);
for i=1:1:n
fprintf('Received frame %d:',i);
disp(a(i,1:t+1));
end
f=zeros(1,n);
for i=1:1:n
f(i)=rem(sum(a(i,1:t+1)),2);
if(f(i)==1)
p=i;
end
end
if(f==0)
fprintf('ACKNOWLEDGEMENT RECEIVED\n');
else
fprintf('Frame%d is REJECTED\n',p);
disp('RETRANSMITTING....');
a(p,q)=~a(p,q);
for i=p
fprintf('Received frame %d:',i);
disp(a(i,1:t+1));
end
end
m=m-n;
end
```

output of this program

```
Enter the total no of frames:5
Enter the window size:3
Enter the length of frames:4


Transmitting frame 1 :
     1     1     0     1     1

Transmitting frame 2 :
     1     0     0     1     0

Transmitting frame 3 :
     1     1     0     1     1

Received frame 1:     1     1     0     1     1

Received frame 2:     1     0     0     1     0

Received frame 3:     1     1     1     1     1

Frame3 is REJECTED
RETRANSMITTING....
Received frame 3:     1     1     0     1     1

Transmitting frame 1 :
     0     0     1     1     0

Transmitting frame 2 :
     1     1     0     1     1

Received frame 1:     0     0     1     1     0

Received frame 2:     1     1     0     1     1

ACKNOWLEDGEMENT RECEIVED
>>
```

i need to change the randomly generated frames as dynamic by user and no constrain on length of frame ( want to enter frames with different length)

Comment: Enter the total no of frames:4
Enter the window size:3


Enter a frame: [ 1 0 0 1 ]
??? Undefined function or variable 'a'.

Error in ==> selectiverepeat at 25
    a_temp(1:size(a,1),1:size(a,2))=a;

Comment: but 'acknowledgement received' is not getting displayed at the end of all frames received

Comment: the previously answered question for splitting up the bits and this program needs to be appended. the output of the previous question which is splitted are the frames need to be transmitted in this program.

Comment: My code had a few errors. I've fixed them; it should work fine now.

Comment: it works :) but how do i append the splitted bits from previous question s answer as frames tat needs to be transmitted

Comment: but acknowledgement should be received after transmission of all frames. if number of frames is 4 and size of window is 3, acknowledgement should be displayed after receiving 4th frame and not after receiving 3rd frame ( because window size is 3 )

Comment: So the `x` values from the previous question are the frames here?

Comment: Also, since you're checking for correctness after every window, shouldn't "ACKNOWLEDGEMENT RECEIVED" be printed after every window and not after all the frames?

Comment: x is the whole information and the resultant split up are frames that is needed to be sent. if x=  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0, and if the split up is 1 0 0 , 0 1 & 1 0 0 . then frames are 1 0 0 , 0 1 & 1 0 0. these are transmitted with this program.

Comment: Awesome.. I'm happy to hear that. :)

Comment: @Roney Micheal :can u kindly explain me the code?

Comment: @Roney Michael:hello are u der

Comment: i have another program which needs to be split like the previous program. with the same logic am not able 2 split it. can u help?

Comment: Of course. Post it as usual. I'll give it a go; you may even get help from someone else.

Comment: i have posted the program in previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want each frame to be entered by the user and the length of one frame might be different from the next.

If this is the case, you could use the following code:

```
clear;
close;
clc;

m=input('Enter the total no of frames:');
n=input('Enter the window size:');
a=-ones(n,1);
max=0;
disp(sprintf('\n'));

while(m~=0)
    if(m<n)
        n=m;
    end

    for i=1:1:n;
        while(1)
            d=input('Enter a frame: ');    %To be input as, for example, [0 1 1 0]
            if((size(d,1)~=1 && size(d,2)~=1) || length(size(d))~=2)
                disp('Invalid input! Frame must be an one dimensional array. Try again.');
                continue;
            else
                break;
            end
        end
        t=length(d);
        if(t>max)
            max=t;
            a_temp=-(ones(n,t+2));
            a_temp(1:size(a,1),1:size(a,2))=a;
            a=a_temp;
        end
        d(t+1)=rem(sum(d),2);
        a(i,1:t+1)=d;
        disp(sprintf('Transmitting frame %d :',i));
        disp(a(i,1:t+1));
    end

    p=[find(a==1);find(a==0)];
    q=ceil(rand()*length(p));
    if(q==0)
        q=1;
    end
    a(q)=randint(1,1);

    for i=1:1:n
        t=find(a(i,:)==-1,1)-2;
        fprintf('Received frame %d:',i);
        disp(a(i,1:t+1));
    end

    f=zeros(1,n);
    for i=1:1:n
        t=find(a(i,:)==-1,1)-2;
        f(i)=rem(sum(a(i,1:t+1)),2);
        if(f(i)==1)
            p=i;
        end
    end

    if(f==0)
        fprintf('ACKNOWLEDGEMENT RECEIVED\n');
    else
        fprintf('Frame%d is REJECTED\n',p);
        disp('RETRANSMITTING....');
        a(q)=~a(q);
        for i=p
            t=find(a(i,:)==-1,1)-2;
            fprintf('Received frame %d:',i);
            disp(a(i,1:t+1));
        end
    end

    m=m-n;
end
```

### EDIT

You need the `d` from the previous question for this; replace d in the previous question with something else, say, `d_indices`.

Add the line `j=1;` to end of the previous code.

Now add this current code (without `clear`) to the end of the previous code and make the following changes:

1. Replace `m=input('Enter the total no of frames:');` with `m=length(d_indices)-1;`.
2. Replace `d=input('Enter a frame: ');` with

> ```
> j=j+1;
> if(j>length(d_indices)
>     break;
> end
> d=x((d_indices(j-1)+1):d_indices(j));
> ```

I haven't tried it out yet, but you should be good to go.

Comment: @durga: It's the same logic code as before, only modified a bit so that no necessary value gets overwritten.